# Why are the left exact functors from an abelian category to abelian groups cocomplete and have a injective generator?

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories, homological-algebra

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an abelian category, $\mathcal{Ab}$ the category of abelian groups and $Lex(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{B})$ the category of left exact functors between abelian categories.

**What is the simplest way (or at least a way) to prove that $Lex(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{Ab})$ is cocomplete and has an injective cogenerator?**

Comment: OK, $\mathcal C$ is an abelian category, but what's this relevant for? I think this question is very poorly stated, and I also think that a proof of this fact can be quickly found in the standard literature on the topic. 

Comment: This was a typo, i am sorry. It is corrected now.

Answer (score 3):

A complete proof, albeit in German, is given in Section 4.13 of B. Pareigis, *Kategorien und Funktoren,* Teubner, Stuttgart (1969).